# How do I take a 24 volt DC 10-30 kHz PWM signal from a Click Plus PLC and convert it to a 5 volt DC PWM signal to control a pump?

Tags: pwm, voltage-divider, plc

I am working on a small dose spraying system for a farming application. I have a Click Plus PLC, part number [C2-01CPU-2](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/programmable_controllers/click_plus_plcs_(stackable_micro_modular)/cpus/c2-01cpu-2), and it has one IO card so far, a [C2-14D2](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/programmable_controllers/click_plus_plcs_(stackable_micro_modular)/cpu_option_slot_modules/c2-14d2). I want the PLC to control a Kamoer diaphragm pump [KLP180-E-B12](https://www.kamoer.com/us/product/detail.html?id=10056) using the PWM signal. I was attempting to run the 24 volt DC PWM signal through a Wago DC to DC Converter [859-801](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/power_products_(electrical)/dc-to-dc_converters/din_rail_mount/859-801) to get a 5 volt DC PWM signal, but it doesn't seem to be functioning correctly. I have a feeling the cycle speed is what is causing me issues. I would prefer to not add another card to my PLC for space saving reasons, but if I have to, I can. I feel like a voltage divider should do the trick, but I am a mechanical engineer... not an electrical engineer! Would someone be able to advise me on this?

Pump Info Below:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you need to power it with the same signal or is this just a low current control signal? If the latter, have you tried to just use a voltage divider?

Comment: The pump has a 12 volt input, ground, PWM, and speed output, so I think a voltage divider would work right? I just don't know what I should use for resistors?

Comment: How about 18k/4k7?

Comment: For the pump ``PWM`` input do you have the details of the the voltage / current required for the input? I tried clicking the KLP180 Product Manual download link for the KLP180-E-B12, but I would need to create an account to obtain the manual. If a 5 V CMOS logic input the current required is probably low, but worth checking to size the resistors to give reliable operation.

Comment: Thanks for that input! Is there a way I can post the PDF on here?OK I uploaded what small information there is in the Product Manual.

Comment: DC-DC converters are for changing the voltage of *power* lines, and are not suitable for changing the voltage of *signal* lines. They can't turn on and off quickly enough for a signal of any usable speed to make it through. Changing signal levels is easily achieved with much simpler methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the comments suggested a resistor divider, from the pump information I'm not sure what the input impedance is.

Given the C2-14D2 supports currents of up to 0.1 A was thinking using a zener diode to supply a 4.7 V high input to the pump PWM input and be able to deliver several mA. This is a variation of the other [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/695019/101063) which mentions using a logic gate as a buffer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEmDxL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where:

- R1 limits the current used in the divider to under 10 mA. Needs a resistor rated for at least 0.25 W
- D1 is a 4.7 V zener diode to give a logic high voltage
- R3 serves as a pull-down to allow a logic low level when the PLC output is off
- The other components simulate the *Equivalent Output Circuit* of the C2-14D2 output module in the PLC

Comment: I really appreciate the input! I have the pump here in my shop. Can I measure the ohms from the PWM wire to ground? Or measure the current going through the PWM wire? With this information, would we be able to decide if we could use just a voltage divider or a zener diode?

Comment: @RyanVine Do you happen to have an oscilloscope available? If yes, then you could use a resistor divider and measure the voltage at the PWM pump.

Comment: @RyanVine The PWM input to the pump is probably an input to active semiconductor device, rather than just a resistor, and therefore trying to measure the ohms with a multimeter will give a misleading result. The suggestion from Andrew Morton to use an oscilloscope to measure the voltage at the PWM pump after connecting a resistor divider is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

> *I feel like a voltage divider should do the trick, but I am a mechanical engineer... not an electrical engineer! Would someone be
> able to advise me on this?*

If all you want to achieve is a reduction in amplitude whilst keeping the same frequency and duty cycle then a voltage divider made from two resistors will do the trick. However, you may want to buffer the output of the voltage divider using a logic gate so that it can drive the pump's control input.

Comment: What does the logic gate help me with?

Comment: @RyanVine it acts as a buffer and thus can delver several mA to the pump's control input without causing disruption to the effectiveness of the voltage divider.

Comment: "Buffer" in this context means an amplifier.  If your pump input is either capacitve or resistive, then a resistive divider will be slow or wimpy, respectively.  A buffer would have a vastly lower output impedance than any sensible resistive divider could.